# How to print to stdout from out of proc ATL com object?

Tags: c++, atl

I am writing a COM object, using ATL in C++. I am implementing it as an out of proc server, meaning it will run as its own process. Is there a way to print output in the COM implementation so that it will be accessible/shown for the calling process?

For example, I would like to create and use the COM object in a VBS script called from cmd.exe, and show the output on that console. I would ideally like to handle this in my implementation of the COM object, rather than make it the responsibility of the calling process to configure.

Comment: can you elaborate more about your question, what code you already have, and possible trace or error message resulting from compilation or runtime?

Comment: @A.Rashad I've got a functioning COM object, save for output, so there are no errors to report. I'm looking for something similar to how stdout would work in a traditional console application, except that it is successfully redirected to the process calling the COM object.

Comment: This could only ever work if the client program is itself a console mode app, something that the server has no control over.  But then the output of the client program and your output will be intermingled with no way to avoid it unless the client and server negotiate about it.